# Activity restarts when called from service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview, android-service

I have a service in my app of  a floating button (like facebook messenger)
and when clicked , my activity returns from the background , but it doesn't return in the same way it was when it was minified , it starts over calling onCreate once more , any idea what causes this behavior ?

In my manifest the acivity is with property :

```
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and it is called by my service like so :

```
    Intent i = new Intent(FloatingViewService.this, DrawerActivity2.class);
    i.putExtra("fromController",true);
    i.setFlags(FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    FloatingViewService.this.startActivity(i);
```

My main problem is inside the activity i have a webview and it's reloading everytime the button is clicked and calls the activity instead of just staying the same way.

After the update this is my activity in the manifest

```
        <activity
        android:name=".DrawerActivity2"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/OtherTheme"/>
```

**UPDATE 2**

It might be worth to mention , it's a library that sits in an app.

I tried this code for opening the activity :

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName()); startActivity(intent);
```

and it opened the first(of the original app) activity and not the one that is open.

any help will be appreaciated

Comment: post your manifest please.

Comment: when do you add singleTask as launchmode? which method is getting called? Oncreate? or onNewIntent?

Comment: Well I didn't override onNewIntent but onCreate is being called everytime

Comment: added more info on question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only imagine what your `FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND` means. And I wonder if it called so cause you had some crashes before with something like "activity could be launched without FLAG_NEW_TASK from applicationContext bla bla". Whatever.

So if you have there `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` you will always get your `DrawerActivity2` instantiated in **NEW_TASK**. It will always be, you know "new one" activity. 
And changing `launchMode` to `singleTop` won't give expected result. [Read about launchModes and Flags here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManagingTasks)

Note you're not allowed to launch Activity within same `TASK` with an `ApplicationContext`(or `BaseContext/ContextWrapper` that `Service` extends). For that purpose **you have to** use **Context of an Activity** for **starting new** `Activity`

And about `Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName()); startActivity(intent);`
Probably it works as expected

> The current implementation looks first for a main activity in the
>   category Intent.CATEGORY_INFO, and next for a main activity in the
>   category Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER. Returns null if neither are found.

[Android developers source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)%22source%22)

And you ask

> my activity returns from the background, it starts over calling onCreate once more , any idea what causes this
>   behavior ?

My assumption is **FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND**:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FloatingViewService.this, DrawerActivity2.class);
    i.putExtra("fromController",true);
    i.setFlags(FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND); /*is it really Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ???*/
    FloatingViewService.this.startActivity(i);
```

How to fix it ? Probably to startActivity with ActivityContext instead of ApplicationContext. But this is different story to tell. And can't recommend a "good" way of how to implement it.

Comment: great  answer , Is there a simple way to get the activity context to a service ?

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to have activity within Service ? Is there another way to improve your app ? 
If there is no other way as a last resort I would use  Background Activity without any layout. And I probably would save it in Application class as static field. And I would clear that reference when Service called onDestroy()

Comment: well , the service is a floating button that starts when a call comes in , pressing it will cause a return to the dailer , and another to return to the activity and so on ... what would you do in this situation?

Comment: A simple way to get the activity context to a service could be that you launch a activity which launches the DrawerActivity2. If you set the launcherActivity noHistory to true and finish it should have the expected result.

Comment: @yanivtwin were you actually able to solve your problem with this answe? What did you change? I don't see anything helpful here. I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
<activity
        android:name=".DrawerActivity2"
        android:launchMode = "singleInstance" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use launchMode singleTop and i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) it should work, but only if the activity is on top of the stack.

If you cannot ensure that the activity is on top of the stack, it is worth a try to set launchMode to singleTask and i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)